# How to tell someone that he could arrange a meeting at another time?

Tags: email

I sent an email to someone to arrange a meeting , I had written that "Sunday will be good for me ".

But today is Sunday and until now I didn't receive a response from him.
So i want to send him another email, and tell him that tomorrow and the day after after are good too.

What should I write ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. "Tomorrow and the day after are good for me" is perfectly acceptable English.

Comment: @DJClayworth How could I say the day after tomorrow and after after tomorrow , I mean without tomorrow !

Comment: You could write "The day after tomorrow or the day after that". But if I was doing it today (Sunday) I would write "Tuesday or Wednesday". By the way, we have an [English Language Learners site](http://ell.stackexchange.com) which is good for questions like this.

Comment: But "tomorrow" and the "day after after" would be _Monday and Wednesday_!  Also, I would start by saying "Sorry, I didn't see your request until just now (Sunday at hh:mm)."

Answer (score 1):

This is partly an email etiquette question. The guy didn't respond at all, and now you need to write to him again, and try to get him to respond this time. You want to get his attention -- hey guy, please don't ignore my message! -- But also, you don't want to irritate him, because they he'd be less likely to respond at all.

> I hope we can schedule a meeting for early this week.  Monday or Wednesday would work well for me.
>
> I look forward to receiving your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, unless it's an agreement to someone's invitation, "Sunday will be good for me" was questionably too direct; "Sunday would be good for me" is more of an open-ended suggestion.